# Django: change field from Int / Char to ForgeinKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

If I have the following model:

```
Order:
  customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
```

Can I just a create an empty migration, with code to create a fk on the table and just change the code to:

```
Order:
  customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='orders')
```

Or do I really need a complex migration to save the data etc?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write custom migrations. Just change the field definition as you already shown in question. Then migrate as usual. 
Make sure, currently the `customer_id` contains those values are present in `Customer` model as `pk` value.

Comment: The migtate would want to create a remove column and add column, which is not what I want as I'll lose the data..does that make sense?

Comment: No it should  alter data like this `migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='author',
            name='user_id',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),`

Comment: That would give an error as it would look for `user_id_id` and not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Way to change field from int/char to foreign key:
Order:

`customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)`

Add another backup field and copy customer_id into customer_backup_id

`customer_backup_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)`

create empty migrations take copy  all the customer_id into a customer_backup_id

Add  customer field in model

`customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='orders')`

Create another empty migration

get customer from db using id customer_backup_id, and save into order.